# How to get absolute path of geckdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, path, selenium-firefoxdriver, python-os

I am using selenium webdriver, for which I have to configure geckodriver,for which I am using following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from pathlib import Path

geckodriver_path = os.getcwd()+'\\'+'geckodriver.exe'
print(geckodriver_path)
new_path = (os.path.join(str(os.getcwd()), 'geckodriver.exe'))

driver = webdriver.Firefox(new_path)
```

whenever I storing geckdriver within webdriver, it shows me following error:

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\taimoor.pasha\\PycharmProjects\\web_Automation\\geckodriver.exe'
```

I have used everything, like 'joins', 'sep', abs' everything, which is used in os libraray. Can someone help me here.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the same directory as the script? That's the only thing that worked consistently for me.

Comment: Also, might as well get rid of the outer parenthesis here `(os.path.join(str(os.getcwd()), 'geckodriver.exe'))`

Comment: @Ares I have put it on same directory and the point of using os.getcwd() was to make sure that if I am using from another system or any other environment, I shouldn't bother about changing path.

Comment: SuperStew , it needs to be there, as It is file name and I have to give the name on strings.

Answer (score 1):

After Checking all answers, I found answer from one of the websites, it should work like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_path)
```

and it worked like charmed :)